# Convert datatable column to list

Tags: c#, datatable

I build method which would convert specific datatable column values into a list of specific type, most like it will be List of string. Nevertheless, the problem I face when datatable column was the type of `decimal` or any other and I wanted to get result as `List<string>` I get error for instance: decimal to string exception. What should i change inside my method to fix that?

```
//for example here colname is decimal i want still my list to be List<string> containing that decimals as strings
    var myList = GetSpecificColumnValuesFromDatatableToList<string>(mydt, "colname");

    public List<T> GetSpecificColumnValuesFromDatatableToList<T>(DataTable datatable, string colName)
    {
         List<T> list = datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<T>(colName)).ToList();          
         return list;
    }
```

Comment: *Don't* use `string`. Use the correct type, eg `GetSpecificColumnValuesFromDatatableToList<decimal>`

Comment: but then i will get List of decimal. Notice that i want to get List of string and in this particural case my datatable column is of type decimal so somehow thise column decimal has to be converted to string.

Comment: You still have to use `<decimal>` since the value is *not* a string and can't be converted to a string. You need to use either `ToString()` or `String.Format` to format the decimals to a string, eg inside a `Select`: `GetSpecificColumnValuesFromDatatableToList<decimal>().Select(d=>d.ToString("#00.00")).ToList();`. Or create a different method that does this before calling `ToList`

Comment: Your method should likely be List<string> instead so T can be decimal, or introduce another generic T2 to separate return from convert.

Comment: The *problem* is using the wrong type. The solution is to use the *correct* type. If you want to *format* decimals to strings, you need to use the correct methods. If you wanted the method to only return strings, it should call `ToString()` in its `Select` lambda

Comment: You *can't* convert a decimal or any other binary type to a string. You *format* to string. To do that you use the appropriate methods. Besides what would that decimal look like? `12345,67` or `12 345.67` ?

Comment: so what you are saying is if i have decimals i cannot put in in list<string> to be treaded as strings? Dim variable1 = "11111.12" not possible?

Comment: I'm saying you misunderstood types, strings and formatting. Not lists. You *can't* write `string x=3.45;`

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more level of generics to your method and provide a converter expression so that you can convert the whole list of values to the type you want.

```
var myList = GetSpecificColumnValuesFromDatatableToList<decimal, string>(mydt, "colname", v => c.ToString("0.##"));

public List<TResult> GetSpecificColumnValuesFromDatatableToList<TColumn, TResult>(DataTable datatable, string colName, Func<TColumn, TResult> converter)
{
     return datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => converter(r.Field<TColumn>(colName))).ToList();          
}
```

For a more convenient way, I suggest making this an extension method:

```
var myList = mydt.ConvertColumn<decimal, string>("colname", v => v.ToString("0.##"));

static class DataTableExtension 
{
    public static List<TResult> ConvertColumn<TColumn, TResult>(this DataTable datatable, string colName, Func<TColumn, TResult> converter)
    {
         return datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => converter(r.Field<TColumn>(colName))).ToList();          
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, do i really need to tell what datatable column type is? Asking because we have huge datatable with diffrent columns types. Can it be just i want to say to this format not saying what datatable column type is?

Comment: If you just want to convert the column value to string without any formatting, and if you will never need conversion between types (e.g. a long(bigint) column to short(tinyint)), then you don't have to write a method. Just use this line everywhere: datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<TColumn>(colName).ToString())